# Why there is no 'end' in my For loop when I use algorithm2e package in Latex?

Tags: latex

I am using the latex to write a Pseudo code about my algorithm,but there is no 'end' in my For loop when I use algorithm2e package?I use it like in the following way:

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\For{$k=1$ \KwTo $n$}
{   
$P=A*P*A^{T}$
}
\end{algorithm}
```

There is no 'end' for my for loop, does anyone know why?

[image: latex pseudo code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `vlined` option you explicitly tell algorithm2e to replace the `end` with a vertical line. If you want an `end`, don't do that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\For{$k=1$ \KwTo $n$}
{   
$P=A*P*A^{T}$
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]